# How to set the selector of navigation icon in toolbar?

Tags: android, selector, toolbar, material-design

When I'm using the toolbar of material design, I can set the navigation icon through 
`mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);`

But the shape of navigation icon selector is round when icon is onpressed, how can I make a square selector of navigation icon in toolbar? And how can I disable ripple animation on selector?
My style is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeBase">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/myNavigationColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
    <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/toolbar_elevation</item>
    <item name="android:transitionName">actionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Are you testing on API=21? I think square onPressed view is the default for API<=20.

Comment: @miav Yes, I'm using api 21, can I change the default view shape?

Answer (score 3):

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selector</item>
```

This is the only way that I am aware of. Note that this acts on a deep level and might override the background of other widgets as well, so you might want to test it. If you do so, let me know.

I used this for a while, trying to have a round background on APIs < 21 instead of the square one. Your goal should be easier to achieve, because a square background selector can be good for the whole application (while a round background feels good only on icons).
So suggested code might be good for your needs.

Comment: Good work, it also changes background color of action mode icons. Of course you need to write selector for press states. What is min API of this?

Comment: Is it possible to set the background selector of all action items, to be of a specific color? Currently, when using style "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar", it sets the background selector to be white-ish ripple on Lollipop and above.